# how to Play .flv files in WPF?

Tags: wpf, flash

How to Play .flv files in WPF? please anyone help me out.

Answer (score 3):

```
// Create the interop host control.
var host = new WindowsFormsHost();

// Create the ActiveX control.
var axShockwaveFlash = new AxShockwaveFlash();

// Assign the ActiveX control as the host control's child.
host.Child = axShockwaveFlash;

// Add the interop host control to the Grid
// control's collection of child controls.
this.MainGrid.Children.Add(host);

axShockwaveFlash.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
axShockwaveFlash.LoadMovie(0, @"C:\player.swf");
axShockwaveFlash.SetVariable("quality", "Low");
axShockwaveFlash.ScaleMode = 0;
axShockwaveFlash.AllowScriptAccess = "always";

//axShockwaveFlash.FlashVars =  @"file=C:\barsandtone.flv" + 
//&autostart=true&fullscreen=true&controlbar=none&repeat=" +
//"always&stretching=fill";

axShockwaveFlash.CallFunction("<invoke name=\"loadFLV\" " +
    "returntype=\"xml\"><arguments><string>barsandtone.flv</string>" +
    "</arguments></invoke>");

axShockwaveFlash.Play();
```

**Reference**:

- [Hosting Flash movie in a WPF project](http://www.infosysblogs.com/microsoft/2008/07/hosting_flash_movie_in_a_wpf_p.html)
- [Hosting Flash Movie in WPF (Part 2)](http://www.infosysblogs.com/microsoft/2008/08/hosting_flash_movie_in_wpf_par.html): Some ‘Strictly Microsoft Technology Please’ options

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use DirectShow, you must use WPFMediaKit.

With http://www.free-codecs.com/download/K_lite_codec_pack.htm it will be ok.

Max @GoTactile

Answer (score -1):

If thats using DirectShow then you probably just need a codec installed:

http://www.free-codecs.com/download/K_lite_codec_pack.htm