# Which file formats can an embedded flash player in WPF plays ? Is it only SWF?

Tags: c#, wpf, activex, axshockwaveflash, embedded-flashplayer

I have embedded an **axShockwaveFlash** in my WPF , When I want to set the media through **LoadMovie** method or Movie property , I can give a local `*.swf` and see the result , but If i give an **Mp4 (h.264)** I do not see anything ! 
Before this one I have embedded **VLC player plugin** and I could give different types. Can Flash player only play `swf` ?! Then how come youtube use it ? I feel I am totally mixed up !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The axShockwaveFlash can only open swf files. to play video formats using this control, you should use a player.swf (that made by adobe flash to play flv files) like the one youtube using.

The player.swf contains the seek bar, volume button and other options.

so you should load a player.swf inside axShockwavwFlash and load the flv file inside this player.

Here is an example of [loading flv video inside axShockwaveFlash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689110/how-to-play-flv-files-in-wpf). to play other formats you can [embed Windows Media Player](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383953.aspx) inside your win form.